# How to disable pop-up view but not multi-window programatically in devices having this feature?

Tags: android, multi-window

I am working on an App and wanted to implement a functionality such that the user can use the App in Multi-window but not in pop-up view.
I have both of these features available on my device LG G8x, Samsung devices also has these features.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.